# Can't use "state variable" inside useeffect to filter an arrray

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code. number_of_rooms is updated in another component. It successfully updates, I console.logged it. But I can't use it inside useEffect. Instead of "number_of_rooms", I tried a static variable "5", it works. But I can't use the state variable (number_of_rooms) to filter the array. Can anyone help?

```js
const[number_of_rooms, setRoom] = useState(null);

useEffect(()=>{    

      const neww = test.filter(property => property.numberofrooms === number_of_rooms);
      console.log(neww)
        
},[number_of_rooms]);
```

Comment: is `number_of_rooms` updated by an `onChange` in an `<input />` element ? if so, consider that the type provided by `e.target.value` will be a string and not a number, therefore, if `property.numberofrooms` is of type number, the filter callback will always return false

Comment: I tried your code example and it seems to work. Are you sure that your filter expression is correct? (Your Codeexample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-p6bh1r?file=App.tsx) Btw, I would recommend to stick with camel-case.

Comment: Thank you very much Aylo. Yes! number_of_rooms is updated by an onChange in an <input /> element so I had to use parseInt(number_of_rooms ) and it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Web() {
  const [numRooms, setNumRooms] = useState([]);
  const number_of_rooms = 5;
  const test = [
    {
      hotel: "A",
      numberofrooms: 5
    },
    {
      hotel: "B",
      numberofrooms: 5
    },
    {
      hotel: "C",
      numberofrooms: 3
    }
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    const neww = test.filter(
      (property) => property.numberofrooms === number_of_rooms
    );
    console.log(neww);
    setNumRooms(neww);
  }, []);

  return <div>
    {numRooms.map(numRoom => <h1>{JSON.stringify(numRoom)}</h1>)}
  </div>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-williamson-0xcwtb?file=/src/App.js